# Was the o in "go" and oe in "toe" pronounced differently in early 19th century Gloucestershire English?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, historical-change

No modern dialect makes the <o> and <oe> distinction, but when reading Medhurst's Hokkien dictionary of 1832 i came across (page 34)
[image: koe]
[image: ko]

Furthermore, <o> seems to be a monophthong and <oe> a diphthong (page 37):
[image: vowels]

From this description, it would appear that <o> = /o/ and <oe> = /əu/ or /ou/. But the Hokkien characters are pronounced with /o/ and /ɔ/, which later transcriptions attest to.

EDIT: Medhurst was born and studied in London but grew up in Gloucestershire, so i have edited the title.

Comment: Given his vague descriptions "16 *ae* something like *i*" and his upbringing in Gloucestershire (strong accent) at the turn of the 18th century, I wonder if Medhurst were not using his own speech patterns as a control/baseline.

Comment: I'd guess that "co in co-equal" might have a shorter vowel than in "toe", because the stress is in the first syllable of equal. So it could be partly about that.

Comment: By "Hokkien", are you referring to a Chinese dialect?

Comment: @Lawrence The distinction between a "language" and a "dialect" as spoken in China is controversial, but see [Hokkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokkien) on Wikipedia, where it's described as "a variety of Chinese".

Comment: It's interesting that in Japanese, the sound lengths for those characters are reversed: 沽 is *ko* (コ, one syllable) and 高 is *kou* (コウ, two syllables). These would be the *on* (Chinese) readings.

Comment: "No modern dialect makes the <o> and <oe> distinction — there are some dialects of American English that would use [o] in *flooring* and [ou] in *toe ring*.

Comment: @Greybeard Wikipedia says he was born and studied in London though.

Comment: @StuartF Hmm, Hokkien does not have a length distinction, but maybe length affects the vowel quality in English?

Comment: @iamanigeeit This is irrelevant: in his day, people were far more likely to retain an accent than lose it.

Comment: @Robusto 高 was probably /kau/ in Middle Chinese and followed the development of 道 /dau/ → /dɔː/ → /doː/ (according to Wiktionary)

Comment: @Greybeard He was using English descriptions to spell the Hokkien words, so he spelt /ai/ as "ae" and said it sounded like "i".

Comment: @Greybeard Good point -- updating the question to Gloucestershire English.

Comment: @Greybeard Interestingly Gloucester itself (previously spelt with "Glow-") is pronounced with /ɒ/, closer to /ɔ/. Do you have any data on West Country English vowels?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I recognise the accent but no more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description does seem to pretty clearly describe a diphthong along the lines of /ou/ for Hokkien 沽 (while less clearly saying that English *toe* and *hoe* have something similar, but apparently pronounced with a less "full mouth"), but not 高.

As Stuart F said, it seems possible that the contrast between *toe/hoe* and *co-* might refer to a difference in vowel length caused by stress. *Co-equal* certainly has the primary stress on the second rather than the first syllable. It's hard to say without context, but *go* would be relatively unstressed in the context of phrases like "go out" or "go along with", although it would take fuller stress in a sentence like "He ought to go."

Per the Oxford English Dictionary, the word *hoe* did originally have a more diphthongized vowel than *go*. However, at the time it was pronounced that way, it wasn't normally spelled *hoe.* *Hoe* derives from French *houe* and had spellings like *howe, howwe, houe* in Middle English:

> The spelling *hoe* (due to the falling together of *-ōw, -oe,* in pronunciation, as in *flow, floe*) appeared in 18th cent., and became the ordinary form c1755. *How, hough,* are still dialectal; the Scots is *howe* /hʌu/, /hou/, rhyming with Scots pronunciation of *grow, knowe,* etc.

This means the difference in spelling between "o" in "go" and "oe" in "hoe" doesn't actually mark the original phonemic contrast between these words: it's just one of the many inconsistencies of modern English spelling.

Despite their apparently contrasting use in the guide, it seems unlikely to me that Walter Henry Medhurst would have made a phonemic distinction in his usual pronunciation between the vowels of *go* and *hoe.*

The fact that Medhurst cites the word *toe* as a rhyme for *hoe* strongly implies that he did not maintain the original distinction between a diphthong and long vowel in this case, because *toe* did not originally come from an u-final diphthong: it comes from Old English *tā,* and so has the same original vowel as *go* (from Old English *gān*). Conceivably, Medhurst could have had an accent where the distinction was confused but not yet entirely lost.

Medhurst seems to have been born in London in 1796.
His father was initially an innkeeper in Ross-on-Wye, Herefordshire (where I assume Medhurst resided until the age of 11, although I haven't found confirmation of this); the family later moved to Gloucestershire. Walter attended St Paul's School in London [from July 1807](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_National_Biography,_1885-1900/Medhurst,_Walter_Henry_(1796-1857)) (aged 11) [to 1810](https://bdcconline.net/en/stories/walter-henry-medhurst), after which he moved to live with his parents in Gloucestershire, and then departed for China in 1816.

I don't know what characterized the English spoken in Herefordshire/Gloucestershire/the  West Midlands in Medhurst's time.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Toe%E2%80%93tow_merger) says of the *Toe–tow* merger that

> In 19th century England, the distinction was still very widespread; the main areas with the merger were in the northern Home Counties and parts of the Midlands.

Comment: The Hokkien vowel for 沽 is definitely /ɔ/ though, although not as rounded and more central than the English one. It's sometimes written as "aw" in names like Haw Par 虎豹 and Khaw 許.

Comment: As Greybeard has said, Medhurst grew up in Gloucestershire. I don't have access to data on its vowels, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_English uses /o:/ for "no" and /ou/ for "low". Listening to the Bristol recording from https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/bristol-dialect-pat-childhood i hear "alone" (0:31) with /ɔ:/ and "go" (0:55) with /o/.

Comment: @iamanigeeit No, that's not *alone* that she's saying there at 0:33; it's *on the lawn*, which of course has /ɔ/  as one would expect in that last word. That being said, she **does** have interesting /o/ vowels.

Comment: @tchrist Now that you say it, i wonder why i heard "take us out all alone" instead of "take us out on the lawn"...

Comment: Of course Ross on Wye isn't far from Gloucestershire. I haven't spent much time in Ross but recall that the accent is fairly similar, at least these days. And that's without looking at historic country boundaries

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, I assume Herefordshire vs. Gloucestershire does't make a huge difference; I was just trying to write out the facts to clarify to myself the timeline of when Medhurst lived where.

Comment: According to [here](https://www.soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/language/Gmc_W_Eng_EW_SW_Som_Emgt), long o is [œ̝̈ˑʏ] in Somerset, which could explain why Medhurst describes /ou/ as "full mouth".

Comment: @iamanigeeit but Somerset is really quite a different accent to Gloucestershire

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that Medhurst might have recorded the speech of different regions and combined them.

In Teochew and other Minnan-speaking regions near the Fujian-Canton border, 高 is /ko/ (phonetically [kɔ] ~ [kʌ]) and 沽 is /kou/. I find it strange that any <strike>language, let alone</strike>  Sinitic language would differentiate [o] and [ou].

References:

- Pronunciation by geographical distribution [here](http://www.kaom.net/si_word.php)
- [Audio of 高](https://www.mogher.com/%E9%AB%98) in Teochew
- [Audio of 沽](https://www.mogher.com/%E6%B2%BD) in Teochew

Comment: Some accents of English differentiate [o] and [ou]. In many American dialects, *pouring* is /porɪŋ/, while *toe ring* is /tourɪŋ/. They're not perfect rhymes.

Comment: I'm looking for minimal pairs -- i think herrison's link to the toe-tow merger describes it quite well.